# Does accessing a false Boolean value in $_POST return false or null?

Tags: php

I am sending `x = false;` Boolean value through the POST method. Will `Request::post['x']` or `$_POST['x']` return Boolean `false` or `null`?

If I try `(!isset($_POST['x']))` it gives me `true`, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Can you share more of the code where you are using this? Also, `(!isset($_POST['x']))` returning `true` means that `x` is *not* set (i.e. null).

Comment: Can you show how you're sending the post data? Are you using `curl`?

Comment: Why don't you just do `var_dump($_POST);` to see what's received?

Comment: Note that POST data is not typed, everything is a string.

Comment: Yes. Using curl.

Comment: @Chris but i m sending a bool data. And sending boolean false means i m setting it

Comment: @Barmar its empty. But when i send true its 1

Comment: Then you have your answer. False values are not put into the post data.

Comment: Why? Will it be null?. The problem is i m picking the value from another function which only returns true or false

Comment: @CH_user303 Perhaps just checking `(isset($_POST['x']))` will be enough. True means true and false means null (i.e. false).

Comment: `(!isset($_POST['x'] ))` gives true because it is set....... to something

Comment: Welcome, to improve your next experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Can you please add the actual code, it'll be easier to check ti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that using `!` (the NOT logical operator), means that `(!isset($_POST['x'] ))` will return `true` if `x` is not set (i.e. null).

All data in `$_POST` is untyped; it is all a string. If you need to send Boolean values, one option would be to compare a string to `"true"` or `"false"`.

```
if ($_POST['x'] === "true") {
    // True
} elseif ($_POST['x'] === "false") {
    // False
} else {
    // Error - not equal to true or false string
}
```

A note regarding comparison [operators](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp) in PHP:

`$x == $y` returns true if `$x` is equal to `$y`

`$x === $y` returns true if `$x` is equal to `$y` and they are of the same type

Answer (score 0):

If `$_POST['x']` will contain anything, except `null`, then `isset()` will return `true`.